# Failed to load 7z-JBinding: no 7-Zip-JBinding in java.library.path

Tags: java, 7zip, archlinux

System details: Linux 3.14.21-1-MANJARO x64

Java version: java version "1.8.0_25"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

dependencies installed: java-p7zip-binding and p7zip

I've installed filebot to maintain a media library on my system, however, whenever I execute the program, I get the following error:

```
SevenZipNativeInitializationException: Failed to load 7z-JBinding: no 7-Zip-JBinding in java.library.path
```

As mentioned above, I do have the required dependencies installed.

When I use

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
```

I get this output with my library paths

```
Property settings:
awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
file.encoding = UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
file.separator = /
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.path = .
java.class.version = 52.0
java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext
    /usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre
java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
    /usr/lib64
    /lib64
    /lib
    /usr/lib
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_25-b17
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version = 1.8
java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version = 1.8.0_25
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version = 25.25-b02
line.separator = \n 
os.arch = amd64
os.name = Linux
os.version = 3.14.21-1-MANJARO                                                                                             
path.separator = :                                                                                                         
sun.arch.data.model = 64                                                                                                   
sun.boot.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/resources.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jce.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/classes
sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/amd64
sun.cpu.endian = little
sun.cpu.isalist = 
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level = unknown
user.country = US
user.dir = /usr/lib/amd64
user.home = /home/name
user.language = en
user.name = name
user.timezone =
```

I've added the lib7-Zip-JBinding.so that comes with the java-p7zip-binding package to all of the java.library.path directories in an attempt for it to work, but unfortunately it hasn't.

Any ideas on why I'm getting that failed to load error?

Comment: Related: https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=17777.0

Comment: That manjaro forum post is actually mine, haha. I checked your first link and I don't have java-common. What version of filebot are you using?

Comment: I installed `filebot-4.5-3`. I'm also using `OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_25-b18`. You are using `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_25-b17`. So I'm not sure, but that may be the difference. What is the output of `sudo find / -type f -name 'lib7-Zip-JBinding.so'`? Mine lives here: `/usr/lib/amd64/lib7-Zip-JBinding.so`. Our `java.library.path`'s are otherwise the same, so I'm not sure why you're having difficulties.

Comment: I was using OpenJDK up until yesterday trying to figure this all out. The output has the .so file in a few different locations since I've copied it around trying to nail it down. But I do have it in the same directory as you. I'll try removing everything java related and starting again.

Comment: Certainly odd. I just formatted and reinstalled manjaro, this time only setting up openjdk8 and filebot and the 7zip dependencies and I still get the same error.

The only other real difference that we have is the kernel, but I can't imagine that would be it.

Comment: Actually, I just got it figured out yesterday. I haven't posted the answer yet because I've been busy setting everything back up. from the format. So it turns out that the library paths in `java.library.path` aren't the paths I was looking for. the lib7-Zip-JBinding.so needed to be in my java version's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

!=

```
java.library.path
```

It turns out the path that I needed to fulfill was the

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Which for my version happens to be

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64
```

I would suspect that this would solve this issue for java 7 as well, just use the appropriate directory. Simply copying and pasting the .so file into that directory resulted in immediate success.

Answer (score 0):

I had all the same symptoms on a raspberry pi2, I however was not able to fix with the solution from the op user259861.

Here is what worked for me:

I grabbed the jar file from under the 'Other' heading at http://jdownloader.org/download/offline

1. `mkdir /tmp/jd2`
2. `cd /tmp/jd2`
3. `wget http://installer.jdownloader.org/JDownloader.jar`
4. `sudo java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar JDownloader.jar`
5. `cd libs/`
6. `sudo jar xf sevenzipjbindingLinuxArmVersion.jar`
7. `sudo cp Linux-armpi/lib7-Zip-JBinding.so /usr/share/filebot/`
8. `filebot -script "fn:sysinfo" |grep 7-Zip`

The output of the filebot sysinfo function should now be: `7-Zip-JBinding: OK`

Comment: So is that basically a similar process, but rather a different folder you are copying the .so file to?

Comment: I was unable to get a working lib7-Zip-JBinding.so file elsewhere so I could not solve by updating my path alone.  I needed to obtain a working .so file and also put it into the right place for filebot to work properly